# How to check expiry date of remote ssl certificates

Tags: openssl

I'm testing a one liner that I'll eventually put in a script to do this on a cron. I'd like to take a list of servers and connect to them and check the expiry date of their certificates.

I'm currently using openssl and running a client connect then taking the output and using openssl to get the certificate's information. 
This is what I have so far for the CLI test (which would execute per server) but I'm getting an error. What am I missing?

```
# /usr/local/ssl/bin/openssl s_client -connect my_web_server_ip:443 2>/dev/null | /usr/local/ssl/bin/openssl x509 -noout -dates
unable to load certificate
4274947916:error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line:pem_lib.c:696:Expecting: TRUSTED CERTIFICATE
```

Comment: I'm guessing you fetched of the certificate using `s_client` subcommand but it probably failed and the output was sent to `/dev/null`. You then piped nothing to `x509` subcommand resulting in ***`PEM_read_bio:no start line...`***. If you provide real data, like the server name, then we can probably help you more. You should also use TLS and SNI with `s_client`.

Comment: @jww You were right. When I use the  `# /usr/local/ssl/bin/openssl s_client -connect my_web_server_ip:443`  by itself it does timeout. As far as real data, this is a one liner that I'm testing for a long list of servers. Replacing 'my_web_server_ip' with one of the IPs is not going to help as these are internal servers, and can't be reached by the outside networks anyway. I'm interested in the syntax if I'm doing it right and / or if there are better ways than openssl.  Could you elaborate on the TLS / SNI. Is that a requirement or is that just a best practice?

Answer (score 13):

I know this is an old one, but thought I would answer anyway.

Your syntax is mostly correct:

```
openssl s_client -showcerts -servername example.com -connect example.com:443 | openssl x509 -noout -dates
```

the `-servername` is what you need for OpenSSL to do an SNI request.

EDIT: I should also note that if all you want to know is when the cert is expiring, just toss a grep at the end of that:

`... | grep '^notAfter'`

Comment: Thank you, this is very useful for non-HTTPS TLS services, such as PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 10):

You can also check that using CURL in ***verbose mode by the header***

```
curl -vIk https://www.stackoverflow.com
```

And just look for **Server certificate:** You'll see the ***expiring date*** right bellow it

UPDATE

According to @harlandgomez over the comment section, shortly, we can do:

```
curl https://www.stackoverflow.com -vk 2>&1 | grep 'expire '
```

Comment: skip unnecessary verbosity -> `curl https://www.stackoverflow.com -vk 2>&1 | grep expire`

Answer (score 1):

**Please check cmd to get Needful ans :**

`openssl x509 -noout -text -in abc.cer | grep Not`

> `Output :`

```
   Not Before: Aug 30 10:14:54 2018 GMT
   Not After : Aug 29 10:14:54 2021 GMT
```

Description : Use your `.cer` or `crt` certificate name. `abc.cer` is my certificate.

Comment: This is not a solution to OP's question. because they want to check the expiry of a remote site. So the presumption is that there is no certificate file stored locally.